# Installation for libxml2-dev libonig-dev failed with "connection failed" on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.04

I want to install `libxml2-dev` and `libonig-dev` on Ubuntu 18.04.

I am getting the following error every time I am trying to install it.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libonig-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0 icu-devtools libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin libgraphite2-dev libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-gobject0 libicu-dev libicu-le-hb-dev libicu-le-hb0 libiculx60 libonig4 libpcre16-3
  libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 pkg-config python3-distutils python3-lib2to3 zlib1g-dev
Suggested packages:
  libglib2.0-doc libgraphite2-utils icu-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0 icu-devtools libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin libgraphite2-dev libharfbuzz-dev libharfbuzz-gobject0 libicu-dev libicu-le-hb-dev libicu-le-hb0 libiculx60 libonig-dev libonig4
  libpcre16-3 libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libxml2-dev pkg-config python3-distutils python3-lib2to3 zlib1g-dev
0 upgraded, 22 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 537 kB/13.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 64.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libpcre3-dev amd64 2:8.39-9
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pcre3/libpcre3-dev_8.39-9_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` but it didn't work.

Comment: "Connection failed" looks like a networking issue or temporary server downtime. Try again a bit later and also check if you can reach the internet (or specifically http://archive.ubuntu.com) from a browser or with e.g. `curl`.

Comment: yes I can reach `http://archive.ubuntu.com/` with browser.

Also I am trying it from past three days.

Comment: My telnet report `telnet 91.189.91.23 80.
Trying 91.189.88.152...
Connected to 91.189.88.152.`